# What I can not do inside of an installTapOnBus () method?

Tags: ios, audio, avfoundation, core-audio

What I can not do inside of installTapOnBus() method?

If you reference lecture WWDC 2016  Delivering an Exceptional Audio Experience @ :31 min it mentions that in real time audio I need to not make threads or allocate any memory.

Also this [article](http://teragonaudio.com/article/How-to-do-realtime-recording-with-effect-processing-on-iOS.html) mentions this as well.

The name of the game here is to move anything you can out of the render block and into the initialize function.
This includes things like allocating blocks of memory and calling system functions.

Here is my example code:

```
inputNode?.installTap(onBus: bus,
                 bufferSize: myTapOnBusBufferSize,
                     format: theAudioFormat) {

            (buffer: AVAudioPCMBuffer!,
               time: AVAudioTime!) -> Void in
            theShowInfo.audioFormat = theAudioFormat

            self.onNewBuffer(buffer)
        }
```

Does this mean that inside of my onNewBuffer() function

I can not type the following

```
var myStringArray = ["",""]
```

or this ..

```
DispatchQueue.main.async(qos: .userInteractive) {

        }
```

or this?

```
NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name(rawValue: MyNotificationIdentifier), object: nil)
```

Does it mean that otherwise my app will crash if I will do these calls in threads and allocate memory?

Does it mean that if I do fft algorithm  I need to make all the code for the fft in thread of onNewBuffer function?

Comment: in lecture 502 - AVAudioEngine in Practice => in 22 min . says inside of tap block i can do what ever I need to do with that data

Answer (score 5):

The closure given to InstallTapOnBus isn't called on the audio render thread so you don't have to worry about locks here.  The render callbacks are set using the C API.  If you were using a render callback, then yes, you would avoid any Swift Functions, Objective-C messages, assignments that take ownership of ObjC objects (ARC), allocations, or anything else that might take a lock or potentially take too long to return.